Batch Rename and Move Files with CMD
I wonder if someone can help me with running some code as a batch file with CMD.
I have a list of files in a directory, that i wish to replace the filename e.g. "Myprefix-" with "Thisisnew_" and move the files to a new location.
File names are currently like MyPrefix-INVOICE1_C.PDF
I would like them replaced with Thisisnew_INVOICE_C.PDF
Then move them into another directory (not copy)
I have found this script, but even when I add pause to the end, I cant see what the issue is as it does not run.
@ECHO ON

SET Loc1Dir=D:\sql\Reports\Mycustomer\Incoming
SET Loc2Dir=D:\sql\Reports\Mycustomer\PDF

CD /D "%Loc1Dir%" 
FOR /R %%F IN ("*-*.PDF") DO CALL :copyFile %%~F %%~NXF
GOTO: EOF 

:copyFile
SET copyfname=%~1
SET fname=%~2 
SET fname=%fname:MyPrefix-=Thisisnew_% 
ECHO F | XCOPY /Y /F "%copyfname%" "%Loc2Dir%\%fname%"
:::XCOPY /Y /F "%copyfname%" "%Loc2Dir%\"
:::REN "%copyfname%" "%fname%"
GOTO :EOF


How do you know it doesn't run? Do you double-click on the script (don't do that) or do you open a command prompt and launch it from there?

double clicking on the batch file doesn't do anything.  Will try it direct from command prompt, thanks for the idea :)

At least I get an error this way. File Not Found - %~1

Looks like he doesn't know that he needs to fill in something there, he thinks that %~1 is the actual filename. But I have no idea how to solve this.

I'm copying the above code into command prompt ?

Well there's your problem right there. %~1 and %~2 are the first and second arguments that are passed to the script; you can't just run the lines one at a time. Also, you use %%F in scripts and %F on the command line.

@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

SET "Loc1Dir=U:\sql\Reports\Mycustomer\Incoming"
SET "Loc2Dir=U:\sql\Reports\Mycustomer\PDF"

CD /D "%Loc1Dir%" 
FOR /R %%E IN ("myprefix-*.PDF") DO CALL :copyFile "%%~E" "%%~NXE"
GOTO :EOF 

:copyFile
SET "fname=%~2"
SET "fname=%fname:MyPrefix-=Thisisnew_%" 
ECHO MOVE "%~1" "%Loc2Dir%\%fname%" 
GOTO :EOF

Note:
I use U: for testing, so any drive references have been changed.
Changes:

Insert setlocal. This ensures that changes made to the environment from running one batch does not pollute the environment for the next batch run in the same cmd instance.

Use set "var=value" for setting string values - this avoids potential
problems caused by trailing spaces.

Use required prefix in the filemask so that files myprefix-* only are detected. This eliminates the possibility of detecting a file named NOTmyprefix-* and changing that to NOTThisisnew_*

I prefer to avoid ADFNPSTXZ (in either case) as metavariables (loop-control variables) as ADFNPSTXZ are also metavariable-modifiers which can lead to difficult-to-find bugs (See for/f from the prompt for documentation) - metavariable changed from F to E

Quoted parameters delivered to subroutine to avoid potential problems with spaces.

Syntax error - GOTO: EOF should be GOTO :EOF

Relevant move command constructed and echoed for verification. To activate once verified, remove echo keyword. Append >nul to  suppress ...file(s) copied report.

To view the report when using point-click-and-giggle methodology, insert the PAUSE line after the for... line



I seem to have this working now.
New to Batch scripting and did not realize :::lines were commented out.
I switched the bottom 2 lines and it seemed to work
REN "%copyfname%" "%fname%"
echo F | XCOPY /Y /F "%fname%" "%Loc2Dir%\%fname%"


:: is a broken (unreachable) label, often used as a comment as it's visually less intrusive that REM. BUT to insert a remark within a code block (parenthesised sequence of lines) you need to use REM as labels are most disruptive within a code block.
